# connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream for nginx+php-fpm docker

Tags: php, symfony, docker, nginx

### Introduction

I want to create a site that is powered by `php-fpm`, `nginx` and `docker` and I want to have `php-fpm` and `nginx` on separate containers. To do this, I followed [this tutorial](http://geekyplatypus.com/dockerise-your-php-application-with-nginx-and-php7-fpm/) but am stuck now when accessing my web server under `localhost:8000`. My browser displays a 502 and my `/var/log/nginx/project_error.log` is full with

`[error] 7#7: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.20.0.1, server: app, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost:8000"`

### Searched answers

I already searched a bit for this topic and found these threads:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/827781/docker-nginx-and-php7-error-111-connection-refused-while-connecting-to-upstream
- https://serverfault.com/questions/546349/what-is-the-difference-between-using-upstream-and-location-for-php-fpm
- https://serverfault.com/questions/840970/nginx-connect-failed-111-connection-refused-while-connecting-to-upstream

However, none of them solved my problems.

### Files

I [created a GitHub repository](https://github.com/tzfrs/dockertest) containing all files, so anyone can simply check it out there (I think it's better than having all files dumped in here). To do that, simply do

`git clone git@github.com:tzfrs/dockertest.git`
`mkdir -p citynavigator/public`
`touch citynavigator/public/index.php`

In addition to that, here is the code

General

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "2"
services:
    db:
        image: mysql:5.6
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=citynavigatorrootpass
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=citynavigator
          - MYSQL_USER=citynavigator
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=citynavigatorpass
        volumes:
          - /var/lib/mysql

    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        volumes:
            - ../citynavigator:/var/www/app
            - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
            - ./nginx/app.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            - ./nginx/fastcgi_params:/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
        links:
            - php
        networks:
            - code-network

    php:
        build: fpm/
        volumes:
            - ../citynavigator:/var/www/app
        networks:
            - code-network

networks:
    code-network:
        driver: bridge
```

`fpm/Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

LABEL maintainer="Theo Tzaferis<t.tzfrs@gmail.com>"

USER root

RUN rm /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/docker.conf \
    && rm /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf \
    && rm /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf.default \
    && rm /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf \
    && rm -rf /var/www/html

ADD app.pool.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/app.pool.conf
```

`fpm/app.pool.conf`

```
[app]
user = www-data
group = www-data

listen = 127.0.0.1:9000

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 20
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3

catch_workers_output = yes
```

`nginx/app.conf`

```
upstream php-upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
    server_name app;
    root /var/www/app/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        # optionally set the value of the environment variables used in the application
        # fastcgi_param APP_ENV prod;
        # fastcgi_param APP_SECRET <app-secret-id>;
        # fastcgi_param DATABASE_URL "mysql://db_user:db_pass@host:3306/db_name";

        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/index.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

`nginx/fastcgi_params`

```
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;

fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING            $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD          $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE            $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH          $content_length;

fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME             $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO               $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param   PATH_TRANSLATED         $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI             $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI            $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT           $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL         $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE       CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE         nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR             $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT             $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR             $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT             $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME             $server_name;

fastcgi_param   HTTPS                   $https;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
# fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS         200;

# Allow 10 minute script execution time
fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
```

`nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  2048;
  multi_accept on;
  use epoll;
}

http {
  server_tokens off;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 15;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log off;
  error_log off;
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript image/svg+xml;
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  open_file_cache max=100;
  client_max_body_size 30m;
}
```

Comment: I added the code to the question as well.

Comment: I had a quick peek and spotted two things that may need correction: 1. Both `nginx` and `php-fpm` use `127.0.0.1` but this is not the case - separate containers have a separate address given by `code-network` network. 2. In your `app.conf`, using `realpath_root` (IMO) is really suitable when both `nginx 
 and `php-fpm` are running on the same virtual box. Try replacing that with `$document_root` var instead if you want to run this across multiple containers. I may be able to provide more info later today, but this is what I was able to spill out now...

Comment: Hi, I changed `realpath_root` to `document_root`. To your first point: Do you mean that I have to set the ip of the `nginx` container in `fpm/app.pool.conf` and the ip of the `php-fpm` container in `nginx/app.conf`?

Comment: I think I fixed it for now. I changed `fastcgi_pass` to `fastcgi_pass php:9000;` and now it works without problems, finally. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction

Comment: [Creating a simple PHP-FPM, Nginx and MySQL application with docker compose](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/zpbw/creating-a-simple-php-fpm-nginx-and-mysql-application-with-docker-compose). This is cleaner version than yours.

Comment: It doesn't look that much different. How is it cleaner? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is cause the 127.0.0.1 should be the name of your php service not the localhost

So change

```
fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
```

to

```
fastcgi_pass php:9000;
```

Or similar in the used upstream directive.

`php` is reachable from your nginx if its in the same network (which obvously is through **code-network**)

Comment: Gonna accept this answer, since the solution was only in the `comments` and it's probably better for users to see this answer directly.